# Date formatting in UITextField when entering a date using UIDatePicker (in UIActionSheet) in SWIFT

Tags: swift, ios8, datepicker, nsdateformatter, uiactionsheet

I would like to create a UITextField that when touched will activate the UIDatePicker in an ActionSheet manner. While there are some resources out there, it doesn't show how to **format the date** in this manner. The code below is the best I've located from stackoverflow, but doesn't give a format for the date:

```
import UIKit

class SignUpViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

var datePicker:UIDatePicker!

@IBOutlet weak var dateTextField: UITextField!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // UI DATE PICKER SETUP

    var customView:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 160))
    customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    datePicker = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 160))
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date



    customView.addSubview(datePicker)
    dateTextField.inputView = customView
    var doneButton:UIButton = UIButton (frame: CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 44))
    doneButton.setTitle("Done", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    doneButton.addTarget(self, action: "datePickerSelected", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    doneButton.backgroundColor = UIColor .grayColor()
    dateTextField.inputAccessoryView = doneButton



}


func datePickerSelected() {
    dateTextField.text = datePicker.date.description
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What isn't working? The date doesn't have the format you want? Take a look at `NSDateFormatter`.

Also:

- There is no need to create a wrapper view for the picker: just assign to to `inputView` straight away
- Do not use `UITextField` for that: it isn't a *text* field after all! Not only is it dangerous since you can't easily disable input through an external keyboard, but also do the semantics suck for accessibility. Instead create a custom `UIControl` subclass and display the text using a label. You can assign your input view here.

Comment: If you don't mind, could you please post how to implement the NSDateFormatter into the code above?

Comment: @MartinQ I leave that up to you, there are enough resources on how to accomplish that here on StackOverflow.